how do i put image on a button android studio
i have an png image 512x512px of a gear(for settings) and i want it to put on a button.
i have tried to create a directory in drawable to keep things organized but that didnt work ether so i put the png inside drawable and set the button to that image that i think its wrong thing to do, with so many png's inside the drawable it creates a big mess. i have tried the image assets but it only changes the app icon only(or maybe i dont know how to use it). vector assets need svg, i have tried to convert png to svg but didnt work.

The easiest way to handle png resources I found so far is using 'Resource Manager'. You can find it in the top left corner of Android Studio.
Select 'Import Drawables', select the image, and then import. Once imported, it can be accessed in the same way as any other drawable.


i have done that import and it does not always work. for example when i want to set it to a button
android:background="@drawable/gear"
the button still appears with purple color, even with the
app:useMaterialThemeColors="false"
does not work

@lukalutidze Can you post the result you want? Maybe you're looking for ImageButton.

Oh, you are right i need imagebutton, Thanks!

@lukalutidze If you don't need the background in the ImageButton, set background to ?attr/selectableItemBackground. If you found this answer useful, It would be very grateful if you accept it.

All set, got what i needed thanks, how do i accept the answer? and is there any way to store this png's in a folder somewhere? because its really messy in drawable cause i have many other pictures to put.

@lukalutidze Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no way to create subdirectory in drawables. So I usually keep the drawables directory closed and use Resource Manager when I want to find a drawable.
